# C# - Can't Use Class in WCF Client

Tags: c#, class, wcf, client

I have the following class in my WCF Server:

```
    public class ResponseModel<T>
    {
            public string DeveloperMessage { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan RequestTime { get; set; }
            public virtual T RetrievedData { get; set; }
    }
```

I use the endpoint of my WCF server in a client application and I imported it like this:[image]

and then added the webreference. I instantiated the service:

```
   ManagementAgentServices.SynchTriggerWcfService Service = new ManagementAgentServices.SynchTriggerWcfService();
```

I want to use the `ResponseModel` in my class but however I can only use this and it doesn't work :

```
    ManagementAgentServices.ResponseModelOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj Response = new ManagementAgentServices.ResponseModelOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj();
```

How am I suppose to create it like this ?

```
    ManagementAgentServices.ResponseModel<string> Response = new ManagementAgentServices.ResponseModel<string>();
```

Comment: What does "doesn´t work" mean? What error do you get?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I should be able to use it like this : 'ManagementAgentServices.ResponseModel<string> Response' but I cant

Comment: What exactly do you export / import as the service?  Because WCF doesn't do `<T>`.  I can't figure out the question here.

Comment: so if I use it like this : ResponseModel<string> , will it work ?

Comment: In wcf you normally have to decorate everything with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`

Comment: what is the error exact error you are getting?

Comment: there isn't an error , but I can't instantiate the class properly like on the server side, `ResponseModelOfArrayOfstringuHEDJ7Dj` shouldn't it be `ResponseModel<>`